# Check div's display CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I do something like this?

Example I have 2 divs:

I wanna do something like this...
If 'some-class' display=none;
then
'some-other-class' display=none;

What do I need to use to do something like this jQuery, javascript?
Thank you.

Comment: I would outsource the display=none to a new CSS-Class. Then I would apply this CSS-Class to the two divs. If then edit the class via javascript, then it effects all elements with this class. Btw.: jQuery is only a Javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can use:

```
$('.element').is(':visible') 
   ? $('.other-class').hide() 
   : $('.other-class').show()
```

Or with vanillaJS

```
element.style.display === 'block' 
  ? other_element.style.display = 'block'
  : other_element.style.display = 'none'
```

Or even better way (I think)

```
other_element.style.display = element.style.display
```

The last way take the `element` style display value and assign to `other_element` style display.

Comment: I would ntoe, that you shouldn't use `.style` in JS in 2021 anymore. The modern approach should be to use `.classList` to add, remove or toggle classes for multiple reasons such as possible specificity weight issues

Comment: You can still use `.style` if you want an inline style. If only display something, it doesn't matter but if there are many css property that need to handle, yes, you should use `classList`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method taking advantage of css variables. I set a variable named `--class-display` on the root element, and then I can use that variable in any place throughout my css. When I want to hide that element, I can use js to change the root variable property, and it will apply throughout my css.

```js
document.querySelector(".someClass")
  .addEventListener("click", async () => {
    const root = document.documentElement.style;
    root.setProperty("--class-display", "none");
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    root.setProperty("--class-display", "block");
  });
```

```css
:root {
  --class-display: block;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
div {
  height: 4rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
.someClass, .otherClass {
  display: var(--class-display);
}
```

```html
<div class="someClass"><b>CLICK ME</b></div>
<div class="otherClass"></div>
```